# Django - Membership matching query does not exist

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I'm trying to create a subscription style service on Django (using Django3)
Basically, I had it working..ish, but my stripe customer keys weren't being added in, so I fiddled around to get that sorted.
Now I'm getting this error - `Membership matching query does not exist.`  this is whenever I'm trying to create an account, login or login to the admin of my Django project.

I can't really figure out what the issue is, as I've reverted the changes I made to get the cust-Id (any tips here would be appreciated! lol)  working again, but it's still throwing it up at me.

Here's my code in my models, I can't even pinpoint where this issue is coming from if I'm honest.    (I got this mostly from the JustDjango tutorial btw!)

The debug thing is saying it's to do with the `free_membership` variable in the `post_save_usermembership_create` method though.

So far I just have models.py and admin.py done to get this up & running -

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

from datetime import datetime
import stripe
stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY


MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES = (
    ('Regular', 'reg'),
    ('Premium', 'premium'),
    ('Free', 'free')
)


class Membership(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    membership_type = models.CharField(
        choices=MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES,
        default='Free',
        max_length=30)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=15)
    stripe_plan_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.membership_type


class UserMembership(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripe_customer_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    membership = models.ForeignKey(
        Membership, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username


def post_save_usermembership_create(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    user_membership, created = UserMembership.objects.get_or_create(
        user=instance)


    if user_membership.stripe_customer_id is None or user_membership.stripe_customer_id == '':
        new_customer_id = stripe.Customer.create(email=instance.email)
        free_membership = Membership.objects.get(membership_type='Free')
        user_membership.stripe_customer_id = new_customer_id['id']
        user_membership.membership = free_membership
        user_membership.save()


post_save.connect(post_save_usermembership_create,
                  sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)


class Subscription(models.Model):
    user_membership = models.ForeignKey(
        UserMembership, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    stripe_subscription_id = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_membership.user.username
```

Comment: Membership.objects.get(membership_type='Free') -> check if you have free membership in database as that is what error states ( matching query does not exist aka. .get() did not return any results)

Comment: @iklinac I can't access the admin page to check though though...any tips on how to do this without that?  I'm still learning Django, so I'm a total newbie to it.

Comment: are you using default database (SQLite or something else) -> https://sqlitebrowser.org/ similar tools exist for other databases you should search for it like -> https://dbeaver.io/

Comment: @iklinac That's exactly what the problem was!  So it turned out I had to create the membership types in my db before putting in the post_save method.  All sorted! Thanks so much! :D